# Getting previous page's results when using skip and limit while querying DocumentDB

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

I have a collection with ~800,000 documents, I am trying to fetch all of them, 5,000 at a time.

When running the following code:

```js
const CHUNK_SIZE = 5000;

let skip = 0;

do {
  matches = await dbClient
    .collection(collectionName)
    .find({})
    .skip(skip)
    .limit(CHUNK_SIZE)
    .toArray();

    // ... some processing
  skip += CHUNK_SIZE;
} while (matches.length)
```

After about 30 iterations, I start getting documents I already received in a previous iteration.

What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess would be to add a sort to the query.

Comment: I tried that, but sorting took forever on such a large collection, and I would have to run it each time I `find()`, so that wasn't an option...

Comment: Add a sort as stated.

Comment: Have you tried applying the sort on the Identifier?

Comment: No, I'll try sorting by the id

Comment: @dutzi any luck?

Comment: @Skami, sorry for the delay, I'm running it now, seems like it's working!

Answer (score 0):

As posted in the comments, you'll have to apply a `.sort()` on the query.
To do so without adding too much performance overhead it would be easiest to do this on the `_id` e.g.

```
.sort(
    { 
        "_id" : 1.0
    }
)
```

Neither MongoDB or the AmazonDocumentDB flavor guarantees implicit result sort ordering without it.

[Amazon DocumentDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/functional-differences.html#functional-differences.result-ordering)

[Mongo Result Ordering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#result-ordering)